# <br/> tag for newline is not working in aiml

Tags: xml, aiml

I am trying to create simple chat application but I am unable to get some part of text in newline.

```
<aiml version="1.0">
<!-- basic_chat.aiml -->

<category>
<pattern>WHO INVENTED LINUX</pattern>
<template>
    Linus Torvalds, along with many open source developers, and the Free Software Foundation, GNU invented Linux.<br/>
    Linus Torvalds invented Linux in 1991.
</template>
</category>
```

Answer (score 0):

at pandorabots the `<br>`
 (or `<br />`) tag works fine. Maybe your interpreter does´nt support it.

Kind regards

Answer (score -1):

You need to close the 
 tag properly. Modified the code as follow and it will append a new line. Tested in playground platform

```
<category>
<pattern>WHO INVENTED LINUX</pattern>
<template>
    Linus Torvalds, along with many open source developers, and the Free Software Foundation, GNU invented Linux.<br><br/>Linus Torvalds invented Linux in 1991.
</template>
</category>
```

Comment: Where exactly did you test this? The OP's example is well-formed XML, yours isn't.

Comment: This is just a category not the whole xml ...

You need to close the <br> tag else it may ceate error while parsing

Comment: You can write either <br/> (the way the OP had it) or <br></br> (with the slash on the other side of the word), but not <br><br/>.

Comment: The <br/> tag in the original question was fine and both <br/> and <br></br> are equivalent. The most likely cause of the issue is the tag is escaped or ignored before being displayed. AIML isn't really designed to have HTML tags embedded in it, as they are not part of the official AIML tag set.